# JQuery file input works locally but not on remote server

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I know it is a silly question but my JQuery File input works on very good locally, but on a abc.com hosting server it doesn't work at all.

Here is my script links:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="<?=base_url()?>http://mcitms.com/spshrm/public/dist/file/css/fileinput.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>http://mcitms.com/spshrm/public/dist/file/js/fileinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>http://mcitms.com/spshrm/public/dist/file/js/fileinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Desired to upload some pdf files to hosting server. Can any one please help me to figure it out my mistake?

**htaccess files**

```
#htaccess Override the URL
<IfModule mod_env.c>
   SetEnv CI_ENV development
#    SetEnv CI_ENV production
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /spshrm
# Prevent CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: When you view your HTML output on the hosting server, what is the value of your script src? What does it show as the value for `<?=base_url()?>public/dist/file/js/fileinput.js`? When you try to visit `<?=base_url()?>public/dist/file/js/fileinput.js` in your browser, is the javascript for handling your file uploads displayed?

Comment: @DragonBobZ. Can you explain further ? .

Comment: Your script tags are attempting to load your `.js` files from somewhere. I am wondering where it is attempting to load them from, and further, if it is succeeding. Depending on how your framework handles that template, if you open up the developer console and inspect the page HTML, you should be able to take a look at your script tags and see what the value of src is. For example, when you run it on your local machine, I would expect it to go from `<?=base_url()?>public/dist/file/js/fileinput.js` to `localhost:3000/public/dist/file/js/fileinput.js`. Similar deal on abc.com.

Comment: @ DragonBobZ. the folder named, "public"  is located in the document root of my Codeigniter project

Comment: And if you go to `abc.com/public/dist/file/js/fileinput.js` does it should javascript? Or does it give you a "Not Found" error?

Comment: @DragonBobZ. Yes. It gives a "Not Found" error.

Comment: @mcode does it not working for the `fileinput.js` file only or not working for the whole files inside the `public` directory?

Comment: @Hasta Dhana. Not working for the whole files inside the public directory

Comment: @mcode do you have a different `htaccess` rules setup between local and remote server?

Comment: @Hasta Dhana. No

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
your_project/application/config/config.php
```

file and change your `base_url` from `localhost` to `abc.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your site in the script tags

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="http://mcitms.com/spshrm/public/dist/file/css/fileinput.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=http://mcitms.com/spshrm/public/dist/file/js/fileinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://mcitms.com/spshrm/public/dist/file/js/fileinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

change **`http://yoursite.com/`** to your **`current site`**

Should be like this above

also check if your **upload folder** is created on website and **check it's folder permission**, change **permission to not less than 775**

Here's a full table of possible numbers and which permissions they are representing:

```
1 --x execute 
2 -w- write 
3 -wx write and execute
4 r-- read
5 r-x read and execute
6 rw- read and write
7 rwx read, write and execute
```

**chmod** your upload folder to at least **775**

Comment: when you go to your http://yoursite.com/public/dist/file/js/fileinput.min.js  what does it shows, not found? have  you checked if your htacess may be blocking the file acess ?

Comment: please check if you are on `correct folder`, and if it's not a `htacess` file that may be blocking the direct  access

Comment: if it's the correct folder so, why it's returning 404 error? please check your htacess files

Comment: could you please post your `.htacess` files?

Comment: @ Otávio Barreto. Added .htacess file

Comment: if you remove your htacess file to another directory like a test directory  does it work or not ?

Comment: @ Otávio Barreto. Not working. But if I change /spshrm as /test that is not working

Comment: could you also tell me your folder structure? since it's giving a 404 error  maybe /public/dist/file/js/fileinput.min.js  is not the correct folder , let me try something I will update the answer

Comment: I think your website maybe is inside `http://yoursite.com/dist/file/css/fileinput.css` try this , so the public folder is the root folder so if my assumption is right it should be this way

Comment: @ Otávio Barreto. Not it is as, http://mcitms.com/spshrm/public/dist/file/css/fileinput.css. As edited post

Comment: Found the solution wait a minute I will update the answer

Comment: Done change your code to my code in the answer and I think it's solved, don't forget to mark answer as right

Comment: @ Otávio Barreto. Are you edited the code of my original post ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198856/discussion-between-mcode-and-otavio-barreto).

Comment: So you also have a problem on The upload script, set the upload folder permisiion to 777 and If folder does not exists create the folder First and than set permission to 777